# Как вызвать процедуру с типом аргумента XMLType? Ошибка: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

Есть процедура, которая принимает одним из аргументов `XMLType`:

```
create or replace procedure p (a in XMLType, b out number) as
begin
    b := a.getRootElement();
end;
```

Взял пример с официального сайта [cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/xml_data_type.html), и пытаюсь так вызвать процедуру:

```
xmldata = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <customer>
        <name>John Smith</name>
        <Age>43</Age>
        <Designation>Professor</Designation>
        <Subject>Mathematics</Subject>
    </customer>"""

root = cursor.var(str)
xmlval = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
xmlval.setvalue(0, xmldata)

cursor.callproc ('p', [xmlval, root])
```

Но выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    cursor.callproc ('p', [xml, root])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P'
```

Как можно вызвать процедуру с типом аргумента `XMLType`?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67453604

Answer (score 3):

Пример из документации описывает поведение в SQL контексте, где допустимо задавать для колонок с типом `XMLType` символьные литералы:

```
create table t (a XMLType) 
/
insert into t values ('<tag>aaa</tag>')
/    
1 row inserted.
```

в PL/SQL контексте это недопостимо и конструктор должен быть вызван явно:

```
var b varchar2(32)
exec p ('<tag>aaa</tag>', :b)

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P'

exec p (XMLType ('<tag>aaa</tag>'), :b)

B
---
tag
```

Так как `XMLType` нативно не поддерживается в cx_Oracle, то надо процедуру вызвать в анонимном блоке и передать только значение для `XMLType` как `CLOB` параметер и вызвать с ним конструктор.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
cursor = cx_Oracle.connect ('connect_string').cursor()
xmldata = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer>
    <name>John Smith</name>
</customer>"""

root = cursor.var (str)
xml = cursor.var (cx_Oracle.CLOB)
xml.setvalue(0, xmldata)

cursor.execute ("begin p (XMLType(:x), :r); end;", [xml, root])
print (f"root is {root.getvalue()}")
# root is customer
```